# Adding invoice lines with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating ASP.NET applications with MVC 4 Technology, and I want to allow the end-user to enter line items onto an invoice. I want the user to have the ability to add as many line items as they wish to the invoice, and then when they are finished to be able to click the Save button on the form which would then write the invoice and all line item data to the database. Can somebody help guide me how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I decided to do it after several other ideas failed me. It may sounds strange, but please bear with me. I used the MVC Index View as a basis.

Before the user even sees the Invoice, I add a new Invoice to the database so that I have an Invoice ID. I then display the Invoice Index View. But instead of the table showing `@foreach (var item in Model)` I changed it to `@foreach (var item in Model.LineItems)`. Its blank now, but after I add some LineItsms I will be displaying a list of LineItems - which is exactly what an invoice is.

But we want to be able to add on our Invoice Index View as well. So at the top of the Index View, in the part where you can code, create a new LineItem and save its LineItem.invoiceID as the Model.ID. Then before you display the table of LineItems add a partial View - Create LineItem.

Now you have a list of Invoice Lines on a page where you can add new ones.

Here's some code from the Index View of LineItem:

```
@model MyAppName.Models.Invoice

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    MyAppName.Models.LineItem line = new LineItem();
    line.invoiceID = Model.ID;
}

<h2>Invoice</h2>

@Html.Partial("Create", line)

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Amount")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Description")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.LineItems)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
        </td>
```

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteConfirmed", new { id = item.invoiceID })
    </td>
    </tr>
}
    <tr>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>R @Model.LineItems.Sum(amt => amt.Amount)</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is what it looks like (except that mine was not an Invoice):

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

You want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Bw5Ey/4/). But it will be much more complex for your case. Use jquery to simplify your work.

```
$('#add_item').click(function() {
    $('#invoice_listing tbody')
        .append(
            "<tr><td>" + $('#item').val() + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + $('#amount').val() + "</td></tr>"
        )
});
```

On every line item being added, the [Add Item] button will fire an event to do a ajax post of the line item data to the MVC controller. The controller will then do business logic and store the line item data into the database. Once the transaction is successful, the controller should return a "success" flag to the client browser. Use JSON for that will help. Your javascript should recognize the "success" flag, and add the item to the item listing.

Then finally, user will pressed on [Save] button, which complete the whole invoice data entry. You should then marked the invoice as successfully entered.

Try not to let user keep on adding the line item without being saved. They will be angry when saving failed after adding lines of item.

Answer (score -1):

Have a popup where your users can search for the line items and add them. When selected capture the `ItemId` and use it to build a row, probably a `tr` or a `div`. So then you will have a `tr` or `div` for each line item that contains the `Id` of the line item and then one or two textboxes. Say a textbox for the quantity and another for the price. Then either do an ajax post where you iterate all the divs and put that info as a json data and post it to your controller method. Or format each div where your binding can collect them and be submitted when you do a postback - via your submit button. That should get you starting.